# Understanding responseEncoding

Tags: asp.net, encoding, utf-8

i have the following:

responseEncoding="utf-8" in the globalization web.config

does that mean if i put the following in my url parameter:

```
%253Cscript%253Ealert%2528%2527vulnerability%2527%2529%253C%252Fscript%253E
```

it will return

```
<script>alert('vulnerability')</script>
```

or will it prevent it from doing so?

i'm a little confused. could someone please show me an example of what the utf-8 encoding really does?

Thank you!

Comment: This may help you: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 encoding in response only means that your webserver supports unicode/utf-8, and has nothing to do with decoding the URL in your example. If you are worried about security issues such as xss attacks, you need to consider html encoding text you get from forms or request params in URLs before presenting them on pages.